# dynamically redirect folders to subdomains on a vagrant vm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vagrant, development-environment, vhosts

I've set up a dev environment using vagrant as per [these](https://github.com/panique/vagrant-lamp-bootstrap) instructions.

This syncs my host folder './' (192.168.22.33/projectname/... or user/myname/sites/mysite) to a fake guest folder on the VM: "/var/www/html"

It works fine as a LAMP stack for the named folder (e.g. mysite), but I want to allow for each folder to be accessed as a subdomain, e.g. for foldername.ip.xip.io to map to ip/foldername

I'd like to be able to create a new folder within 'sites' and then access them by going to:

```
mysite.local.dev or mysite.192.168.22.33 accessing /user/myname/sites/mysite
mysite2.local.dev or mysite2.192.168.22.33 accessing the mysite2 folder.
```

- I've tried using `.htaccess`, which works but I'd like it to be
  invisible and I understand that this isn't best practise.
- I've tried playing around with the document roots.
- I've tried editing `vhosts` during my `install.sh` file and enabling
  `vhost_alias` - but I couldn't get it to work.
- I can only do it for named folders e.g. listing a number of ips in my vagrant file. I don't want to do this as I want to set the vm up such that if I create a new folder (e.g. by pulling a git repo) that it will work automatically, without having to reprovision vagrant every time I created a new subdomain.

I think vhosts must be the right way to do it but I can't get it to work - what have I missed in the below?

Thanks!

My vagrantfile contains:

```
    # Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

    Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
        config.vm.box = "precise32"

        config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080 
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 8443 

        config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install.sh"

        config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
        #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

        # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
        # Default value: false
        # config.ssh.forward_agent = true

        # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
        # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
        # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
        # argument is a set of non-required options.
         config.vm.synced_folder "./myproject", "/var/www/html"
    end
```

My install.sh file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "--- Installing now. ---"

echo "--- Fixing the TTY STDIN error ---"
sed -i 's/^mesg n$/tty -s \&\& mesg n/g' /root/.profile

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- MySQL time ---"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

echo "--- Installing base packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y vim curl python-software-properties

echo "--- Installing PHP5 ---"
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5

echo "--- Updating packages list ---"
sudo apt-get update

echo "--- Installing PHP-specific packages ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core

echo "--- Installing and configuring Xdebug ---"
sudo apt-get install -y php5-xdebug

cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
EOF


# echo "--- Configuring Hosts ---"
# sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
# # setup hosts file
# VHOST=$(cat <<EOF
# <VirtualHost *:80>
#   ServerName vhosts.fqdn
#   ServerAlias *.local.dev
#   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1+
# </VirtualHost>
# EOF
# )
# echo "${VHOST}" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

echo "--- Enabling mod-rewrite ---"
sudo a2enmod rewrite

echo "--- Setting document root ---"
#sudo mkdir "/var/www"
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public/ /var/www/html
#sed -i "s#DocumentRoot /var/www/html#DocumentRoot /var/www#g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

echo "--- Turn errors on ---"
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

echo "--- Set php short open tags to on. ---"
sed -i "s/short_open_tag = .*/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

echo "--- Restarting Apache ---"
sudo service apache2 restart

echo "--- Set up composer ---"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Framework stuff here

echo "--- All set to go! ---"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out.

Editing the vhosts set up as follows, and

```
 echo "--- Configuring Hosts ---"
 #Must be enabled to edit vhosts.
 sudo a2enmod vhost_alias

echo "---Set up home.dev and foldername.dev ---"
    # The first virtualhost redirects home.dev local.dev and localhost.dev to the root dir
    #. The second redirects foldername.dev to site/foldername.
    # %-2 refers to the second parameter from the right of the string.

 # setup hosts file
VHOST=$(cat <<EOF
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias home.dev local.dev localhost.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%-2
</VirtualHost>

EOF
)
echo "${VHOST}" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


#The below is no longer necessary - commented out!
#echo "--- Enabling mod-rewrite ---"
#sudo a2enmod rewrite

#echo "--- Setting document root ---"
#sudo mkdir "/var/www"
#sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
#sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public/ /var/www/html
#sed -i "s#DocumentRoot /var/www/html#DocumentRoot /var/www#g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```